# java mail Api want to show attachment link

Tags: java, email

I'm using the Java mail api to download a file attachment.

following this [tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/download-attachments-in-e-mail-messages-using-javamail)

The problem is that it's doesn't show the download link.

What I want: If the mail contains an attachment then display only the download link and when user clicks on this link then the file should be downloaded.

Comment: The way links are handled & displayed could vary depending on which mail provider you are using to view the email.